# Different behavior in base class __init__ depending on derived class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, derived-class

I have an abstract class `Base` containing a member boolean `do_thing` which will either trigger a one-time action on start-up, or do nothing. This variable can be overridden by a derived class `Derived`, but doing a `super().__init__()` call at the beginning of the `Derived`'s `__init__` leads to the one-time action being always based on what `do_thing` is set to in `Base`.

I only see two options for getting around this, neither of which seem ideal to me:

1. Call `super().__init__()` at the end of every derived class's `__init__` rather than the beginning, which means I can't rely on other default variables set in `Base`.
2. Explicitly call the one-time action at the end of every derived class's `__init__`, which means either duplicated code, or an extra function in `Base` that will only ever be called at startup.

Some example code

```
from abc import ABC

class Base(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.do_thing = False

        # Want to wait for child class init before running this
        if self.do_thing:
            configuration.set(do_thing_parameters) 


class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Should have configs properly set based on this being true
        self.do_thing = True

class RegularDerived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Don't modify the config
```

Is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: You could make `do_thing` into a kwarg with a False default, and then explicitly pass a `True` value in the derived classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "wait for child class init here"? `super().__init__()` runs an ancestor's class `__init__` to completion before you ever set `self.do_thing = True`.

Comment: @JohnGordon That's the way I couldn't think of! If this were an answer I'd accept it. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't expect any implementation code in an **Abstract** Base Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the "do_thing" variable as a default parameter, as shown below...

```
from abc import ABC

class Base(ABC):
    def __init__(self, do_thing=False):
        if do_thing:
            configuration.set(do_thing_parameters) 


class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like your `do_thing` functionality is to do with your classes, not your instances. If that's so, it doesn't seem right to have it as a parameter to `__init__`. You have other options, and I'd go with

A class attribute

```
class Base:
    _do_thing = False

    def __init__(self):
        if self._do_thing:
            configuration.set(do_thing_parameters)

class Derived(Base):
    _do_thing = True

class RegularDerived(Base):
    pass
```

Then you don't even need to define `__init__` in the subclasses